# mongoid_fulltext utf-8 special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, full-text-search, mongoid

I'm building a small rails 3 app using mongodb (and mongoid) for my database. 
I am using the mongoid_fulltext gem (https://github.com/aaw/mongoid_fulltext) to make my database searchable, which has worked fine so far. 
However, I just tried testing the search functionality with words that include the characters 'æøå', and can see that I'm getting some invalid results. 
It looks like mongoid_fulltext ignores these characters, such that the search string "københavn" becomes "kbenhavn".

Does anyone now how to tell mongoid_fulltext to use UTF-8 encoding??

I've added `# encoding: utf-8` To my model and my controller, which doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, so I figured it out. 
If anyone is insterested, here my solution.

You can add special characters by setting the alphabet paramter on you model, as such:

`fulltext_search_in :name, :city, :alphabet => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789'`
 
By default the parameter is set to:
`:alphabet => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'`

Comment: Since you've found an answer to your question, it's also OK to post that below ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. If anyone is insterested, here my solution. You can add special characters by setting the alphabet paramter on you model, as such: fulltext_search_in :name, :city, :alphabet => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzæøå0123456789' By default the parameter is set to: :alphabet => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789'